# Disable cell editing with GridCellChoiceEditor on OSX using keyboard

Tags: wxpython

Given the example code for building a grid with comboboxes from [wiki.wxpython.org](http://wiki.wxpython.org/GridCellChoiceEditor). When navigating the grid using the keyboard, there is no way to disable the cell editing. When pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the dropdown is hidden but the control is still active. Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> does not have any effect.

[image: Problem example]

The [`wx.ComboBox`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ComboBox-class.html) does have an `wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER` event, which allows to handle <kbd>Enter</kbd> presses in the 'locked' state. So, performing a `DisableCellEditControl` inside the handler should stop the editing right? Well, the editor is hidden, but the cursor is still inside the hidden editor. The dropdown can be access when using <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>.

```
def on_text_enter(evt):
    self.grid1.DisableCellEditControl()

self.comboBox.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, on_text_enter)
```

[image: Cursor trapped inside hidden editor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this was another case of rubber duck debugging. Realizing that the focus was still inside the combobox, duck started wondering if restoring the focus manually would solve the problem. And that did it. So for future reference, the event handler:

```
def on_text_enter(evt):
    self.grid1.DisableCellEditControl()
    self.grid1.SetFocus()

 self.comboBox.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, on_text_enter)
```